# Flutter Row scroll Effect animation

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

My current project has a scrollable row which works fine, but I can't find a way to make some kind of static scroll, where when you scroll to an item, the item is centered automatically.

This is what I currently have:

[image: Flutter movie ui]

When the cards are scrolled they stay in the position when the scroll finish:

[image: Flutter movie ui]

The effect I want to accomplish is the card aligning itself in the center when scrolling to the next card.

[image: Flutter movie ui]

Is there a widget that actually works like that?

Comment: You can use pageview builder to accomplish the same with some view port

Comment: you can try [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

Comment: @DungNgo Thanks, i'll save it for another project

Comment: @meditat Thanks, that was what I needed. PageView widget did all the work

Comment: @JoséLuna Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple:

```
 Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 80),
      child: Container(
        child: PageView(
          controller: controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          pageSnapping: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [CardMovie(), CardMovie(), CardMovie()],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

using PageView widget and giving a padding top because the height of the widget was the full screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
 runApp(MyApp()); 
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

final List<String> images = ["Me", "You", "Foo", "Baa"];

final PageController controller = PageController(viewportFraction:0.8);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: images.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Center(child:Text(images[index])),
          color: Colors.grey.shade200
        );

      }
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
 }

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Text('Hello, World!', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
} 
}
```

[image: Here is the output of this code]